# How to check if mouse button is pressed anywhere on screen , even outside of my mainwindow?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, mouseevent

Is it possible to detect mouse buttons pressed inside and outside of my application window in Qt, i guess there is a way to detect mouse clicks inside my application window , but what about detecting clicks inside+outside of main window ?

---

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Can I ask why do you want to detect mouse events that aren't intended for your own application?

Comment: Sure, actually i want to detect UI elements(button/combobox/etc) with the  help of a mouse click , it should work like this,-> if i click on any button on any other app, outside my application window, i need some information of that element in my application

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/windows-automation-api-portal

Comment: @VladFeinstein, yup ,i tried that, need some more help in that

Comment: You could probably write a kernel module / driver thing to intercept mouse events anywhere, but within the Qt framework you are limited to the events that are delivered to your application.

Comment: You could also create a big full-screen invisible object that catches mouse clicks anywhere. Not sure if that fits your use case.

Comment: @JarMan, i don't think that will fit my case, but thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Comment: This question make very little sense. What do you mean by *i need some information of that element*. What kind of information? The "element" is not even part of you application. What information could you possibly get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect mouse buttons pressed inside and outside of my application window in Qt

I don't know if Qt itself provides such functionality, but the underlying OS likely does.  For instance, on Windows, you can use a mouse hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) or [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices) to monitor mouse activity globally.

Comment: Thanks so much Gambit!, i have done some reading and have implemented this function  but getting errors, unhandled exception in call back

Comment: ```LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::mouseProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Q_UNUSED(Code)
        auto& ms = *(const MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (pMouseStruct != nullptr) 
    {  
        if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            qDebug() << "Hames";
            ///How do i get element infor here ?
        }
       // emit instance().mouseEvent();
    }
    // After that you need to return back to the chain hook event handlers
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, Code, wParam, lParam);
}```

Comment: @the_learnist First, don't post code in comments, edit your question instead to add new details. Second, is `mouseProc()` declared as `static`? You can't use a non-static class method for a windows hook callback. Third, are you using `WH_MOUSE` or `WH_MOUSE_LL`? I assume the former. Fourth, why are you ignoring the `Code` parameter? The `wParam` and `lParam` don't have meaningful values if `Code < 0`. Fifth, what errors are you actually getting? Are they compile-time errors or run-time errors? You need to be more specific. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about it ,i just gave an update of whats going on above.can you please suggest any improvements.

Comment: @the_learnist "*i am using WM_MOUSE_LL*" - then use `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` instead of `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT`, [read the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)). And you should be using the mouse coordinates provided in the `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`, not from `GetCursorPos()`. But more importantly, your `automation` variable is *uninitialized*, hence the crash when calling `automation->ElementFromPoint()`. Also, even if everything goes OK, `elem->Release();` needs to be inside the `if` block, in case `ElementFromPoint()` doesn't return an element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, now i am using ```MSLLHOOKSTRUCT```, i have now initialized the values, but still getting the same error, i also tried to print the ```Code``` value , it always prints to 0, i have posted my updated code above. Thanks

Comment: @the_learnist "*i have now initialized the values*" - now you are initializing the `automation` variable to NULL, but you STILL can't call `ElementFromPoint()` on it, it is *undefined behavior* to call class methods via NULL (and uninitialized) pointers. You need to create an actual `CUIAutomation` object (via `CoCreateInstance()`) for `automation` to point at before you can make calls to it. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation).

Comment: I would like to thank you for assistance and patience, this really helped me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221179/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-the-learnist).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, i was not actually initializing `IUIAutomation* automation = NULL;` before using it, now the updated version is

```
BOOL InitializeUIAutomation(IUIAutomation** automation)
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IUIAutomation),
        (void**)automation);
    return (SUCCEEDED(hr));
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindow::mouseProc(int Code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //Q_UNUSED(Code);
        auto& ms = *(const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (pMouseStruct != nullptr)
        {
            if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                qDebug() << "Test Example";

                IUIAutomationElement* elem = NULL;
                IUIAutomation* automation = NULL;
                BOOL stet = InitializeUIAutomation(&automation);  //added this 
                POINT mousePt;
                BSTR elemName = NULL;
                if (stet)
                {
                    GetCursorPos(&mousePt);
                    HRESULT hr = automation->ElementFromPoint(mousePt, &elem); //getting unhandles exception in call back

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && elem != NULL)
                    {
                        elem->get_CurrentName(&elemName);
                        std::wstring ws(elemName, SysStringLen(elemName));
                        // std::wcout << ws << std::endl;
                        QString testing = QString::fromStdWString(ws);
                        qDebug() << testing;
                        elem->Release();
                    }
                    automation->Release();

                    SysFreeString(elemName);
                }
            }
            // emit instance().mouseEvent();
        }
    // After that you need to return back to the chain hook event handlers
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, Code, wParam, lParam);
}

void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event)  // function executed when window is closed.
{
    // Code for destroy
    CoUninitialize();
}
```